# RRAS server 2003 one nic vpn encrypted

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have a a machine installed with Server 2003 standard on it. It is behind a standard adsl router. I have setup RRAS access on it with under the custom setting and selected just vpn as the machine only has one nic installed. I can connect to the server and it all works fine. I'm just wondering where the settings are to say that it is data encrypted. I know in xp when setting up a vpn you can check the option to encrypt the data, but doing this in server 2003 there isn't the option so thought i would try and use rras.

The main reason that i want to do this is that xp only allows one connection at a time.

Dan

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the RRAS console
2. Find 'Remote Access Policies' in the treeview
3. Highlight and right click on the relevant policy
4. Select Properties
5. Click 'Edit Profile'
6. Click the 'Encrption' tab.
7. Ensure all checkboxes except 'No encryption' are checked.